# Clear cache in Windows

Tags: postgresql, cache, windows-10, postgresql-9.6

I would like to make some timing tests in my PostgreSQL database. I would like to clear cache every time I run a query to disable influence of caching on my timing results. I've read some topics about clearing that cache in Linux, but not found how to do that in Windows. Could you help me please?

OS: Windows 10.
PostgreSQL: 9.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to clear the caches easily. On Linux you can stop the database server and use the [drop_caches](https://linux-mm.org/Drop_Caches) facility to clear the OS cache; be sure to heed the warning there to run sync first.

There is also a presentation from [2ndquadrant](https://2ndquadrant.com/en/) that shows [Inside the PostgreSQL Shared Buffer Cache](https://2ndquadrant.com/media/pdfs/talks/InsideBufferCache.pdf). It outlines the following points:

- Windows does not perform well with large shared buffers
  settings. Effective maximum size is around 10,000-50,000
  buffers
- I This talk is more appropriate for UNIX-like platforms; can’t
  really take full advantage of the buffer cache on Windows

Digging deeper into this, I found an open source [project](https://github.com/zilder/pg_dropcache) that clears the cache. I don't see many people forking or using this project though. The safest way is to just restart the server since there is no way to bypass or flush the database's cache. But feel free to look at the code and see if it will work for you.

You can see all prepared statements available in the session by querying the [pg_prepared_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-prepared-statements.html) system view. This will allow you to see if the plan cache was cleared. You might even be able to get away with a [DEALLOCATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-deallocate.html) statement. This might be what you are looking for...

Comment: OK thanks once again and I will check that tomorrow (going to bed to charge batteries ;)) 
(I would rate your answer but I can not since my reputation is under 15)

Comment: Should be able to hit it as the answer, the check box next to my answer :). Let me know if it helps

Comment: Well, I've tried to use mentioned project but I can not install that extension. Executing command: make install USE_PGXS=1 results in:

Comment: Makefile:13: E:/Programy/PostgreSQL/9.6/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'E:/Programy/PostgreSQL/9.6/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk'.  Stop.

And I can not find solution how to solve that problem. It's probably fine in Linux but still not in Windows.

Comment: Your response was the closest one so I will mark it as resolved. Thanks for help.